# Semiopen triangles topology

Tags: general-topology

Consider in $\mathbb{R^2}$ semiopen triangles of vertex $(a, b) \in \mathbb{R^2}$ and width $\varepsilon > 0$ defined by

$$ U =  \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \mid x - y \geq a - b, x + y \geq a + b, a \leq x < a + \varepsilon \}$$

Here is a picture of a triangle:

[image]

Now consider $\mathbb{R^2}$ with topology $\mathcal{T}$, the topolgy which has the triangles as its basis.

I have a couple of questions, to which I'd like to have hints:

1. Is $(\mathbb{R^2}, \mathcal{T})$ a locally compact topological space?
2. Is there some topology $\mathcal{T_1}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathcal{T}$ is the product topology $\mathcal{T_1} \times \mathcal{T_1}$? (My guess is no, since intuitively any topology in $\mathbb{R}$ times itself would give you some sort of square in the plane, but I am unable to rigorously explain this).
3. Is there some topology $\mathcal{T_1}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathcal{T}$ is homeomorphic to the product topology $\mathcal{T_1} \times \mathcal{T_1}$?

   Things I've proven which may be useful: the triangles are open and closed under this topology, the space is not Lindelöf, the only connected sets are points...